# Java List stops updating after Drag and Drop

Tags: java, list, drag-and-drop, tree

I am creating an application that converts files from xml to pptx. The user will drag items from a JTree to a JList to create the slide. I have managed to get everything working but the JList seems to disappear after the drop. I know the drop is received because of print statements, and that it's not null. The JList is still there I believe, because I can print the items in the array. Through testing, I think that something is wrong in the custom DefaultListModel I have created. It is not calling an update/redraw/revalidate after the drop for some reason, or has released its action listeners because I notice that the getSize and getElementAt methods stop getting called after the drop. It does however draw correctly if I add items to the ListModel on app init.

I've been looking through all the documentation on ListModels and TransferHandlers but have not been able to get the List to display after the drop. Is my model missing an Override or not handling listeners in some way?

Full source:
http://code.google.com/p/app4args/

Possible problematic file:
http://code.google.com/p/app4args/source/browse/trunk/src/edu/gatech/app4args/utils/CustomListModel.java

To recreate:

1. Download latest release/source & example xml file from downloads section of project site
2. Run app, choose File > Import, browse to example xml file
3. Create new slide: Slide > New Slide, choose Standard (any works)
4. Drag JTree item from Library to a List in Slide Content View
5. List does not update, clicking on it or elsewhere in the app and back on the list will make it disappear

Thanks

Comment: Does the JList component is removed from the component hierarchy? See if it's parent container still holds a reference to it.

Comment: I believe the parent still has a reference to it, because I can drop as many items as I want to the List and it still adds them as I can see via print statements, but it is still invisible.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: The entire source is available on Google Code, which I linked to. Cutting pieces out of multiple files would only cause confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was overriding methods in CustomListModel that were relevant to the updating of how to draw the content of a list. I removed these and reworked a few things and it is correctly drawing now.